# DB2 ODBC password not used

Tags: db2, odbc, dsn

I have a 32-bit DB2 ODBC DSN created with the user name and password saved. But when I try to connect to the DB I have to enter the user name and password again. Is there any way I can bypass the authentication? I have the user name and password saved in `db2cli.ini` file.

Comment: What tool do you use to check the connection?
Have you tried `db2cli validate -dsn MYALIAS -connect`?

Comment: I tried db2 connect to dbname and it throws the error usernamr and password missing.

Comment: db2 CLP is not a cli application. You can't make it use these UID and PWD cli parameters.

Answer (score 0):

db2 CLP is not a cli application. You can't make it use these UID and PWD cli parameters.